# MC14011 NAND output voltage incorrect

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates

I have a Motorola MC14011CP Quad-dual input NAND IC in which Vdd = 12v. I'm trying to use it as a NOT gate by tying the inputs of one of the gates together. When the inputs are not both true, the output is changing to ~0.5v instead of Vdd +- 0.5v as listed on the datasheet. Could it be something wrong with the chip or have I perhaps made an error in either my component selection or wiring?

Schematic: The Vdd on my IC is tied to +12v and the Vss to 0v. The load is an electromagnet.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4OXoL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: You've broken the device. The MC14011 is rated for VSS at 0V/ground and VDD at +5 to +15V, +18V absolute maximum. This is not what you want to use to drive an electromagnet.

Comment: When you have a single supply, you have +12V & 0V, not +12V & -12V (which would give you 24V in total). If you really did connect a 4000 series IC to 24V you'd have seen the magic smoke leak out. And as others have said, a 4000 series IC is *NOT* suitable for driving a solenoid.

Comment: So it seems I made a pretty obvious error in my description of the circuit, the voltage source has a potential difference of 12v. My positive terminal is at +12v and my negative at 0v. Regardless, I seem to have the wrong chip for the job. Are there any that you would recommend or should I alter more than just the chip in this circuit?

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that your load resistance (an electromagnet) is far too small. The 4000 series should not be asked to put out more than a few mA at 12 volts. Try disconnecting the load and measuring the voltage. Without knowing how much current your magnet requires, I can suggest the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4t1C2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Q1 is just about any n-type power MOSFET, although you'll need to be sure that it can handle the current of the magnet. Likewise, almost any diode will do as long as its current rating is greater than the magnet current.

Comment: To clarify, "_... your load **resistance** (an electromagnet) is far too small ..._". The load is too _great_ for the NAND gate on its own.

Comment: The magnet is rated to operate at 12v DC and 150 mA. Disconnecting the load give me an output from the NAND around 5.6v

Comment: Also, I take it that the inductor in your diagram is the electromagnet?

Comment: @TheEngineEar - Yup. And I suspect that trying to drive the magnet has damaged the gate. Try one of the others in the package.

Comment: Will do, I have just one question regarding the diagram you posted which is: Why the 100 ohm resistor?

Comment: It's just insurance against oscillation. You almost certainly don't need it, and it's not a good idea when doing high-speed switching such as PWM current control, but I'm not certain how well you'll control your ground connections, so I threw it in for luck.

Comment: @transistor - You're right, of course. I've edited. Thanks.

Comment: The gate series resistor, R1, is needed to limit the current through the NAND1 output when charging/discharging the Q1 gate-source capacitance during NAND1 switching. Otherwise it can theoretically damage Q1 or cause NAND1's supply to dip. I would use R1 = 12/IomaxNAND1 myself.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast  I noted President Obama mentioning you in passing tonight on TV. He said something about sometimes being fearful that [**the centre cannot hold**](http://www.potw.org/archive/potw351.html) . Your day may yet come. I'd like to visit Bethlehem myself, but with less publicity.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon - Did he mention anything about the worst being full of passionate intensity? Trump supporters? Clinton supporters?

Comment: He didn't mention that The falcon cannot hear the falconer, OR Things falling apart. It was really all about mere anarchy and blood-dimmed tides being  loosed. He adumbrated re ceremony of innocence being drowned, the best lacking all conviction, and the worsts passionate intensity went without saying. I'm wondering about Hillarus Trumpi - and "a waste of desert sand" may be Iraq. 
What rough beast it is whose hour has come round at last may not be known until the elections.

Comment: Ask my mother. She knows.